# sharethis is not working

Tags: javascript, html, sharethis

I am using `Sharethis` in my website

here is the code which i have added

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "45bd003e-483d-41ec-9f43-b7c7bff3e9b1", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false, onhover:false});</script>
```

this is in my main html

In current html i have this

```
<a class="st_sharethis_custom" st_title="{{profile.displayName}} Profile" st_image="{{profile.profileImage}}" ng-if="loggedIn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span><em>SHARE</em></a>
```

now the problem is when i goto that particular page the glyphicon is loading but on click on that sharethis is not working but if i refresh then it is working

means first time when i am loading the page it is not working but after one refresh it is working.

can someone help me in this
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add this js function

```
$scope.initShare = function() {
        stButtons.locateElements();
    };
```

and add ng-init to the element

```
<a ng-init="initShare()" class="st_sharethis_custom"><img src="resources/scripts/lib/images/share.png" class="icons-s" ></a>
```

then it works...